# The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured Error Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

I recently installed phpMyadmin and getting the following error in My ubntu 14.04.

```
"The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why. 
  Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there."
```

On clicking 'Find out why', It shows the errors below:

```
Create missing phpMyAdmin configuration storage tables.

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] ...    OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] ... not OK
General relation features: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] ...   not OK
Display Features: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] ... not OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] ...    not OK
Designer and creation of PDFs: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] ...  not OK
Displaying Column Comments: Disabled
Browser transformation: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] ...    not OK
Bookmarked SQL query: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] ...  not OK
SQL history: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] ...   not OK
Persistent recently used tables: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] ... not OK
Persistent favorite tables: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] ...    not OK
Persistent tables' UI preferences: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] ... not OK
Tracking: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] ...   not OK
User preferences: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] ...    not OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] ...   not OK
Configurable menus: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] ... not OK
Hide/show navigation items: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] ...    not OK
Saving Query-By-Example searches: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] ...  not OK
Managing Central list of columns: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] ...    not OK
Remembering Designer Settings: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] ... not OK
Saving export templates: Disabled
```

What should I do to clear this error?

Web server:
{Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.47
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
PHP version: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14}

phpMyAdmin:
{Version information: 4.5.5.1deb2.trusty~ppa.1}

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699057/phpmyadmin-configuration-storage-error?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, there was a link on top of phpMyadmin page, asking to create those missing tables. I clicked It and the errors were fixed by itself. :)